# Is it possible to get only partial stored procedure results on error?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatareader

Let's say we have a method with a code like this:

```
Dictionary<int, int> results = new Dictionary<int, int>();

try
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("some connection string"))
    {
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("stored procedure's name here", sqlConn);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //sqlCmd.Parameters.Add lines here
        sqlConn.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader sqlDR = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sqlDR.Read())
            {
                results.Add((int)sqlDR["keyColumnName"], (int)sqlDR["valueColumnName"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch { }

return results;
```

The stored procedure is a select statement with a subselect, both from the same single table, returning multiple rows, no more than several hundred, usually less. Assuming that SP groups results by the key column (so no duplicate key problem in dictionary) and returns `int`s (so no problem with conversion), is it possible to have it return only partial results if any other error occurs?

I'm well aware it's an empty catch block there - if it wasn't empty, I probably wouldn't be asking this question. I also know this code can return an empty dictionary. I was wondering if an exception can break reading from `SqlDataReader` so that results are neither empty nor complete.

I was also told that switching from `SqlDataReader.Read` to loading query results at once with `DataTable.Load(DataReader)` and then filling results from DataTable outside of both `using` statements would avoid getting partial results (that is, if they are possible at all in the code above). Would it though? Does `DataTable.Load` really work differently from `SqlDataReader.Read`?

Comment: What other errors are you expecting? Surely if your SP is able to return _some_ results it will return _all_?

Comment: @ChrisP No idea. Connection timeouts? Deadlocks? Connection pool problems? Network issues? Results from SP got mangled somehow? SqlDataReader couldn't keep reading from the stream? You say 'surely', but I'm not sure about it at all, which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Results are 'created' as the query executes, and send back to the client as they are being created. The reader will read these results as they come and add them to the Dictionary. When and error occurs int he engine, if it occurs, then the execution on the server side is aborted and the error information is sent back and the SqlClient reacts by raising the exception. Read [Understanding How SQL Server executes a query](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/) for more details.

So in your code is absolutely possible to silently return a result that is not empty but also not complete. Aside from the empty catch block, this problem is a just an example in the general anti-pattern of writing code that is not exception safe, in the sense that in the case of exceptions it leaves the application in a state that partially changed and will only trigger more errors later in execution. There is an excelent book on the subject, [Exceptional C++](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/xc++.htm), even though is C++ the principles apply.

The usual workaround is to mutate a *temporary* state and then swap the current state with the desired state in an operation that cannot raise exceptions. In your case that means reading into a dictionary and and then assigning to the return only at the end, *after* the result is entirely read:

```
Dictionary<int, int> results = new Dictionary<int, int>();

try
{
    Dictionary<int, int> temp = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("some connection string"))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader sqlDR = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sqlDR.Read())
            {
                temp.Add((int)sqlDR["keyColumnName"], (int)sqlDR["valueColumnName"]);
            }
        }
    }
    results = temp;
}
catch { }

return results;
```

Another approach is to compensate the actions in the `catch` block. In your case it would mean clearing the `results`. But I much disfavor that approach because it requires keeping the state mutation actions in sync with the compensating actions and over time, if they drift apart, some actions are no longer compensated (undone).

The diligent reader will notice that the two approaches are the code equivalent of the two approaches in database theory for achieving atomicity: [shadow-paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_paging) vs. rollback in [write-ahead logging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_ahead_logging). This is no coincidence, since what you're trying to achieve is atomicity (either all state changes occur or none occurs).

Comment: This still doesn't help you identify "executed correctly; zero rows returned" from "exploded in a shower of sparks". Frankly, IMO the "correct" fix here is simply to remove the `try`/`catch` completely: it isn't helping any. Or at a push, to add an `out ranToCompletion` parameter

Comment: @MarcGravell I completely agree that ignoring exceptions is plain evil. That is so obvious I did not want to even go there. I wanted to answer a more generic question, how to handle state changes in presence of exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The data-reader API is a streaming API, so yes: if there is a *connection* issue, it could happen at any time - including in the middle of a result grid. There would be, however, absolutely no advantage in using a `DataTable` here, as that would fail identically to your existing code in this scenario - if it wasn't for your `catch{}`. It is only the `catch{}` that is causing the "so that results are neither empty nor complete" issue: without the `catch{}`, you would get notified (by an exception) about the problem.

Comment: I know the empty catch block is a problem, but I cannot fix it retrospectively and I'm left with data which might indicate a partial result set returned and possibly an exception swallowed without any trace. EDIT: and I can't easily reproduce that data on the spot.

Comment: @S_F yes, the code shown has exactly that problem. There is no reliable way of knowing that you received all the data. This is self-inflicted by the choice of error handling.

Comment: @S_F out of curiosity: why can you not fix it retrospectively? What is the thing that is preventing that?

Comment: Maybe I used the word incorrectly? I mean the problem already happened and I'm trying to find out what exactly happened by reading code and guessing since I have no exceptions logged for a reason very visible in the code in my question. :)

Comment: @S_F ah, I see; then for something in the past, yes it is entirely possible that you had a connection failure mid-result, and the code returned half the data - or no data when there should have been some. Going forward: ***kill that `catch`***; it is evil.